# Hide content with max-height to hide dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a dropdown list that i can toggle up and down.

My problem is now that the content list is always showing and i am trying to make it only show when its going up and is up. As you can see i have set a max-height to 0 and then to 65vh when toggling it, but the max-height 0 does not seem to do the trick.

I have also tried to change the max-height to only use height and that works but the animation wont work on a height value.

```js
const chooseAreaButton = document.querySelector('.ChooseArea');

$('.ChooseArea .wrapper .parent').click(function() {

  $(chooseAreaButton).toggleClass('top', 400);
  $('.ChooseArea .wrapper .content').toggleClass('active');

});
```

```css
.Container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: flex;
}

.Modal {
  padding: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 87vw;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  // transform: translateX(-900px);
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.ChooseArea.top {
  top: 0;
}

.ChooseArea {
  position: absolute;
  height: 7%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  pointer-events: visible;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $primary;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius 0.1s linear, background 0.1s linear, z-index 0s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  transition: max-height 0.4s linear;
}

.content.active {
  z-index: 3;
  max-height: 65vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content ul {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.content ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(223, 223, 223, 1) !important;
}

.content li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 8vh;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Modal">
    <div class="ChooseArea bottom">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">Choose test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to add is `overflow: hidden;`, see snippet:

```js
const chooseAreaButton = document.querySelector('.ChooseArea');

$('.ChooseArea .wrapper .parent').click(function() {
  $(chooseAreaButton).toggleClass('top', 400);
  $('.ChooseArea .wrapper .content').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.Container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: flex;
}

.Modal {
  padding: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 87vw;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  // transform: translateX(-900px);
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.ChooseArea.top {
  top: 0;
}

.ChooseArea {
  position: absolute;
  height: 7%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  pointer-events: visible;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $primary;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius 0.1s linear, background 0.1s linear, z-index 0s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* <-- ADDED HERE */
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  transition: max-height 0.4s linear;
}

.content.active {
  z-index: 3;
  max-height: 65vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content ul {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.content ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(223, 223, 223, 1) !important;
}

.content li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 8vh;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Modal">
    <div class="ChooseArea bottom">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">Choose test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can do that by changing `bottom` of `ChooseArea` to `10px`. Code below.

You don't need to use the `active` class at all to achieve this.

```js
const chooseAreaButton = document.querySelector('.ChooseArea');

$('.ChooseArea .wrapper .parent').click(function(){

  $(chooseAreaButton).toggleClass('top',400);

});
```

```css
.Container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: flex;
}
.Modal {
  padding: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 87vw;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  // transform: translateX(-900px);
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
  .ChooseArea.top {
    top: 0px;
  }
.ChooseArea {
    position: absolute;
    height: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    pointer-events: visible;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: -10px;
    }
    .wrapper {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
        .parent {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
      line-height: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid $primary;
      color: #000;
      z-index: 999;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transition: border-radius 0.1s linear, background 0.1s linear, z-index 0s linear;
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 18px;
      }
      .content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      display: block;
      z-index: 1;
      max-height: 0;
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 30px;
      transition: max-height 0.4s linear;
    }
    
    .content ul {
      background: green;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
        .content ul a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .content li:hover {
      background-color: rgba(223,223,223,1) !important;
    }
        .content li {
      list-style: none;
      text-align: left;
      color: #888;
      font-size: 14px;
      height: 8vh;
      padding-left: 10px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      }
      .content li:last-of-type {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <div class="Container">
    <div class="Modal">
<div class="ChooseArea bottom">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="content">
              <ul>
                <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
  
              </ul>
          </div>
              <div class="parent">Choose test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```